# adding annotations on ggplot2 causes density plot to disappear

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a number of density plots for a project I'm working on. When I add annotations to the quantile vline that I add to the graph, it causes the density plot to disappear.

```
  d2 <- pt_diff %>%
    summarize(lower = quantile(spread, probs = 0.40),
              upper = quantile(spread, probs = 0.60))
  p <- ggplot(pt_diff, aes(x = spread)) +
        geom_density(aes(fill = 'red')) +
        geom_vline(data = d2, aes(xintercept = lower)) +
        geom_vline(data = d2, aes(xintercept = upper)) +
        ggtitle(paste0(current_week$home.team.name[k],' vs. ', current_week$away.team.name[k]))
```

here the density plot shows up.

[image]

When I annotate the plot:

```
   p <- ggplot(pt_diff, aes(x = spread)) +
         geom_density(aes(fill = 'red')) +
         geom_vline(data = d2, aes(xintercept = lower)) +
         annotate('text', label = round(d2$lower, 2), x = -30, y = 100) + 
         geom_vline(data = d2, aes(xintercept = upper)) +
         annotate('text', label = round(d2$upper,2), x = 4.5, y = 200) +
         ggtitle(paste0(current_week$home.team.name[k],' vs. ', current_week$away.team.name[k]))
```

then the plot disappears:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

thanks.

Comment: My guess: the density plot y-axis is a completely different range than `,d2$lower`. Can't know for certain without having sample data to play with.

Comment: What's strange is if I just make the quantile vlines, then the plot stays. As soon as I annotate them with the actual numbers as labels, then the plot disappears.

Comment: Vlines use the x axis, but I'm talking about the y axis.

Comment: yeah, i see what you're saying now. the y axis range moves from being ~.01 to 100-200.

Comment: If you can accept the text being at the top of the plot region, try `y=Inf`

Comment: thanks for your help. if i change the y of the geom_vline to 0.015-ish, then the density plot comes back into the picture. you were right. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @r2evans already stated in the comments thy y values are to high for the text. Remember you have in 0.0.. y-values.

Here is a solution setting the x and y values of the annotation to the main and max of the values:

```
library(ggplot2)

# random data
set.seed(123)
pt_diff <- data.frame(spread = rnorm(1000))

# quantiles
d2 <- pt_diff %>%
  summarize(lower = quantile(spread, probs = 0.40),
            upper = quantile(spread, probs = 0.60))


ggplot(pt_diff, aes(x = spread)) +
  geom_density(aes(fill = 'red')) +
  geom_vline(data = d2, aes(xintercept = lower)) +
  annotate('text', label = round(d2$lower, 2), x = min(pt_diff$spread), y = max(density(pt_diff$spread)$y)/2) + 
  geom_vline(data = d2, aes(xintercept = upper)) +
  annotate('text', label = round(d2$upper,2), x = max(pt_diff$spread), y = max(density(pt_diff$spread)$y)/2) +
  ylim(0, max(density(pt_diff$spread)$y)*1.5)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Using the density() function was really clever! That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks!